# Excel and PPT Automation in server

Tags: asp.net, automation, ms-office

I have developed an ASP.NET application with following requirement.

**Requirement:**My ASP.NET application having Gridviews and Charts,I need to export these charts into PPT presentaions as a Table and Chart objets not an image.

These are steps I have followed to implement required functionality:

- Prepared an Excel Template with Tables and Charts:This Excel template having macros and these macros I have called from ASP.NET application using COM Interop based on filter selection from UI.Whenever I have called macro by passing parameters excel data updated automatically.
- Prepared an PPT Template,here PPT  Template charts have been copied from Excel and paste with using below option so there has a link b/w Excel and PPT.
- From Excel Macro I am updating these external links whenever data update in Excel so Excel and PPT always match.
- This functionality working exactly similar to my requirement in my local machin.
  I have deployed this ASP.NET application to the server and followed below steps inorder to configure DCOM.

**Steps followes in server inorder to work application:**

1. Install Excel and PowerPoint applications by enabling VBA programming.
2. Dcom configurations:
   Go to the Start-Run menu to type in "dcomcnfg" and hit enter to load "Component Services" MMC.
3. Select the "Microsoft Excel Application" item through "Component Services" MMC->Component Services->Computers->My Computer->DCOM Config->Microsoft Excel Application
4. Right click and select Properties->Select Identity Tab->Selected “The Interactive User”
5. Select Security Tab  ”Use Default” for all options.

With these configurations I have deployed application in IIS and able to run application with out any issues.

But suddenly when I try to access the application its showing below error

I went to “Event Viewer” and issue is as follows.

I gone through the web and found following steps:

1. Go to the Start-Run menu to type in "dcomcnfg" and hit enter to load "Component Services" MMC.
2. Select the "Microsoft Excel Application" item through "Component Services" MMC->Component Services->Computers->My Computer->DCOM Config->Microsoft Excel Application
3. Right click and select Properties->Select Identity Tab->Select This user and add the Administrator accout and password
4. Select Security Tab, Under "Launch and Activation Permissions", Choose "Customize", Click "Edit" button, Add the everyone account and add all the Permissions.
5. Do the same thing in "Access Permissions" and "Configuration Permissions"
   But those are not helping me.

Can anyone help me to configure DCOM on Windows 8 Server in order to run Office Automation applications?

Comment: Try www.pptxbuilder.com

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you follow your steps again, but also do it for MS Powerpoint (set to interactive user)

Steps to follow on the server in order to get the application to work:

1. Install Excel and PowerPoint applications by enabling VBA programming.
2. Dcom configurations: Go to the Start-Run menu, type in "dcomcnfg" and hit Enter to load "Component Services" MMC.
3. Select the "Microsoft POWERPOINT SLIDE" item through "Component Services" MMC->Component Services->Computers->My Computer->DCOM Config->Microsoft POWERPOINT SLIDE
4. Right click and select Properties->Select Identity Tab->Selected “The Interactive User”
5. Select Security Tab ”Use Default” for all options.